# How does the compiler know where I have to place the code?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Not on purpose, I placed the redux `useDispatch` function outside the react component as the following:

[image]

As you can see, the compiler complains. The question is, how does the compiler know, that I have to place `const dispatch = useDispatch()` within component.

Comment: It looks like `eslint` complains instead. Did you set up `eslint` for your IDE?

Comment: That isn't a compiler, it is closer to static code analysis via the ES code linter. If you create your project from create-react-app the hook linting rules are applied by default when you run your project, or in your IDE if you've configured it.

Comment: Front end code isn't compiled, it's transpiled. And it's not the transpiler (likely Babel) that's causing that warning, it's ESLint, which looks at the raw source code and checks for various standards. So if the question is "How does ESLint work internally?" then that's not really on topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: I am using WebStorm.